# Taylor polynomial of $\frac{1+x}{1-x}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I want to study the function $f:[-1,1)\to\mathbb{R}$, $$f(x)=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$$
and some properties regarding the taylor series.

The first task was to calculate the derivates $f^{(n)}$ and to give the taylor series of $f$ in the point $x=0$.

The derivates are for $n\geq 1$ is given by $$f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{2n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}.$$

Then the taylor series for $x=0$ is given by $1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2x^k$.

Next I want to show that the taylor series of $f$ in every point $x\in (-1,1)$ converges against $f(x)$, and also study the case $x=-1$.

Here I am kinda stuck.

For a given $x_0\in (-1,1)$ the taylor series with remainder is given by
$$T_nf(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{f^{(i)}(x_0)}{i!}(x-x_0)^i +R_{n+1}(x).$$

With the Lagrange form of the remainder, we have for some $\xi\in [x,x_0]$ (or $[x_0,x]$) that
$$R_{n+1}(x)=\frac{f^{n+1}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}.$$

I do not see how to preceed from here. I wanted to estimate the remainder, but this didnt work out. Also I think I might be on a wrong track anyways. Can you help me out?

Studying convergens for $x=-1$ one can show that the series converges, by using the formula for $x=-1$ and then applying the quotient test.
This yields that the series converges for all $x\in [-1,1)$. (If I have done no mistake)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perform long division on the given function. Then you only have to worry about a fraction with a constant in the numerator and a linear term in the denominator...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I do not think that the task is meant that way, but I will work that out to see the difference in the effort it takes.

Comment: If you have to find a taylor representation of the given function, that would be the way to go...

Comment: Why? If I work out the long division, I get $1+2x+2x^2+2x^3+\dotso$ while the formula gives the same result.

Comment: But it is easier to do it like this for sure, as you do not have to calculate the derivatives first.

Comment: The given function can be written as $-1+\frac{2}{1-x}$, the latter term being of geometric nature

Comment: Ratio test works for $|x|\lt 1$.  The denominator has a well known power series  $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n$

Comment: @herbsteinberg Yes, I know that you can use the geometric series, but I do not see the connection to my question.

Comment: @imranfat Indeed, but what does that change?

Comment: My main point was that the ratio test can be used to determine convergence domain.  It only fails for $|x|=1$.  Using the geometric series just makes it easier to get Taylor series.

Comment: @Cornman Proving that the series at $x=0$ converges, as you are being suggested to do, doesn't tell you anything about whether the series converges to $f$. If one just adds $e^{-1/x^2}$ to your function, the series at $0$ doesn't change and it doesn't converge to the new function. What you can do is what you were planning. Look at the remainder in Lagrange form. Assume that we are working in $[-d,d]$, with $d<1$. Note that the $f^{(n+1)}(\xi)$ factor is bounded by $\frac{2n!}{d^{n+1}}$. The $(x-0)^{n+1}$ is bounded by $d^{n+1}$. ...

Comment: ... So, the remainder is bounded by $\frac{2}{n+1}$, which tends to zero. That proves that the series converges to the function $f$ at all points in $[-d,d]$, with $d<1$. Therefore, the series converges to $f$ at all points in $(-1,1)$.